# C# WebApi Authorize access functions from dependency injection classes and entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, authorize

I am trying to set up some authorisation for a Web API I have. My project uses Entity framework context, and dependency injection.

I have a Web API function like this:

```
[Authorize2]
[HttpPost]
[Route("whatever")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> APIfunction()
{           
   //Do something...
   return Ok();
}
```

and I have extended the `AuthorizeAttribute` class to this:

```
public class Authorize2 : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actionContext"></param>
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {

    }

}
```

This means that the `OnAuthorization` function will fire before this API function is hit - which is as I want and working fine.

I have a function that is used to determine if the user has permission to access this function. The function is defined in an interface, implemented in a class and the class is instantiated using dependency injection eg:

```
public interface IPermissions
{
   bool hasPermission();
}

public class Permissions : IPermissions
{
   public Permissions(numerous DI interfaces passed into the constructor)
   {
       //Assign values....
   }

   public bool hasPermission()
   {

   {
}
```

and my dependency config has this:

```
container.Register<Permissions, IPermissions>();
```

My issue is that I want to call the `hasPermission` function in my `OnAuthorization` function eg like this:

```
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var perm = _permissions.hasPermission();
    }
```

But I do not know how I can do this, or if it is even possible?

I cannot manually create the classes as there are to many classes and constructors to add it and it is not practical.

I have tried making `Authorize2` implement an interface and then create an instance in my dependency constructor, but that would mean passing in a parameter her `[Authorize2]`, which is not possible.

The only other way I can see is to create this function manually within my `Authorize` class, but I really do not want to do this unless I have to.

Adding this to the to the token is not an option and the data is dynamic and has to be evaluated on a case by case basis

Comment: [this](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=98) may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the attributes do not allow dependency injection, use service location via the `DependencyResolver` which you can get via the `ActionContext`

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
    var resolver = actionContext.RequestContext.Configuration.DependencyResolver;
    var _permissions = (IPermissions)resolver.GetService(typeof(IPermissions));
    var perm = _permissions.hasPermission();

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve dependency using parameterized constructor.

Modify your *Authorize2* class,

```
 public class Authorize2 : AuthorizeAttribute
 { 
     private readonly IPermissions _permissions;
     public Authorize2(IPermissions permissions)
     {
             this._permissions=permissions;
     }
     public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
     {
          var perm = _permissions.hasPermission();
     }
  }
```